# IOS Subscription paid value

Tags: ios

I have configured apple Server-to-Server Notifications and it started to send notification to my webhook but the response body doesn't contain any information about paid value nor currency.
I've searched for endpoint to get that info, with no lock

Comment: Please share your code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple does not include the price in the S2S notification. It is also not present in the receipts validation response (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstorereceipts), but the device does have this information ( not sure how they access it), so we get the price info from the device during validation request it sends to our backend.